# Cannot combine Observable Array to empty Observable array in my angular4 code

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I have written a component using angular 4 and angularfire2, which I get an error in return saying **"ERROR TypeError: _this.memberEvents$.combineLatest is not a function"**.

Please refer following code and point out the way to correct it.

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { MemberService } from './../../member.service';
    import { ClubService } from './../../club.service';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { EventService } from './../../event.service';
    import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { select } from 'ng2-redux';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty' 
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

    @Component({
      selector: 'member-favorite',
      templateUrl: './member-favorite.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./member-favorite.component.css']
    })
    export class MemberFavoriteComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      userId;
      favoriteEvents$;
      memberEvents$ = Observable.of([]);
      id;
      private ngClubsUnsubscribe$ = new Subject();

      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private eventService: EventService, 
        private clubService: ClubService,
        private memberService: MemberService) {
        this.userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
        this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getMemberEvents();
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngClubsUnsubscribe$.next();
        this.ngClubsUnsubscribe$.complete();
      }

      getMemberEvents() {
        this.clubService.getActiveClubs().takeUntil(this.ngClubsUnsubscribe$)
          .subscribe(clubs => {
            clubs.map(c => {
              this.memberService.isMember(c.id, this.userId)
              .take(1)
              .subscribe(res => {
                if(res && res === true) {
                  console.log("user is a member of club ", c.clubname);

                  let clubEvents = this.eventService.getForthCommingEventsOfClub(c.id);
                  this.memberEvents$.combineLatest(clubEvents);
```

**How do I correct this line.
   Is there any other way to do this.**

```
                }
              });
            });
          });
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You call combineLatest directly from `Observable`.

Ex: `Observable.combineLatest(..., ...)`.

If you want to add another stream, based on your example, you can use the `withLatestFrom` operator:

```
this.memberEvents$.withLatestFrom(clubEvents);
```

Comment: Compiler error is gone but results aren't get fetched.

Comment: It's the same code with change you've proposed. this.memberEvents$.withLatestFrom(clubEvents);  I imported 'withLatestForm' operator too.

Comment: I don't see a `subscribe`. The Observable will not activate until a subscribe is present. `this.memberEvents$.withLatestFrom(clubEvents).subscribe(() => { do stuff });`

Comment: I'm subscribing to it in html, using | async. Thing is I don't get any records.

Comment: The emissions must be merged into one array before you may use it in the view. You are joining two source streams, not the data itself. This will join the data: `this.events = this.memberEvents$.withLatestFrom(clubEvents).pipe(map(data => // you need to flatten the data here ))`

Comment: could you please elaborate more. I'm new to this and still cannot make this line work. Will this line work if more observable arrays get added in next iterations.

Comment: Sure. Check this out: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html What I'm trying to convey is you must map (transform) the data sources into one flat array. I'm unsure about the adding of more arrays, but if you post an example I can clarify it.